# Input value to javascript from Android

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am able to send data from java class in android studio to WebView.
The code looks like this:

```
    mWebViewDemo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mWebViewDemo.loadUrl("javascript: (function() 
    {document.getElementById('message').value= 'test';}) ();" );
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    });
```

How do I set a variable to the value so that it's not hardcoded? Or is there any better way to pass value from Android app to WebView?

Comment: A shot into dark: `(var myVar = 'bla'; function() {document.getElementById('message').value= myVar;})`

Comment: @reporter that works! Thanks a lot

Comment: Can I write an answer and you mark this as accepted?

Comment: Sure thanks a lot @reporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your code you create some javascript code. This code contains an anonymous function. A solution is to create a javascript variable with global scope. The pure javascript looks like this:

```
var myVar = 'bla'; 
function() {document.getElementById('message').value= myVar;}
```

So the new java code snippet is:

```
  mWebViewDemo.loadUrl("javascript: (var myVar = 'bla';function()
                       {document.getElementById('message').value= myVar;}) ();");
```

**Note**: The full javascript code should be in one line. I splitted the code here into two lines to avoid a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is completely what you're looking for but since I can't comment yet...

I actually had a similar problem where I had to load a webpage that required some local storage info that was used in the webpage. So i had to inject some JS with the key-value pair in the webpage and than reload it.

I set up my JS code with StringBuilder so I could concat my variable value with it.

There are two options, If you're developing for > API 19 you can make use of the [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) method provided by the WebView instance.

That would look something like this (adapted for your situation):

```
private void setValue(String value) {
    final StringBuilder javascript = new StringBuilder("javascript: (function() {document.getElementById('message').value= '")
          .append(value)
          .append(';}) ();" );

    mWebViewDemo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewDemo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              mWebViewDemo.evaluateJavascript(javascript.toString(), new ValueCallback<String>() {
              //You're javascript has been injected, do something with the callback
             });  
            }
        });
      }
    });
    mWebViewDemo.loadUrl("your.url.com");
}
```

Note how i append the variable value between the hardcoded javascript function.

If you're developing for lower than API 19, you can make use of the loadUrl() function to pass JS.

EDIT: Definitely accept @reporter his answer, as it's to the point and correct, I just thought it was worth mentioning an other way with a more recent method.

Comment: Your answer looks great as well. I'm trying to avoid using loadUrl() if possible.

Comment: Then this method is the way to go :). Give it a try and let me know if you need any help with it. Good luck!